# Repo refusing to sync all contents

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-source

I'm pretty confused what is going on here. I am able to completely sync all (and partially build) of Android, with a VM of these specs:

10GB RAM
400GB SSD storage
9 CPU cores

However, when I go to my second machine with the correct RAM needed to build AOSP, it doesn't download all the code! Repo closes the terminal during the "updating files" portion. I am missing core content such as `system/core`.

Here are the specs of the above machine:

42GB RAM
400GB SSD
5 cores

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by any chance, the development system on which you are facing a problem is running Ubuntu 22.04, it comes with "systemd-oomd" enabled for improving low-memory which in our case it closes the terminal when doing repo sync / build because of high memory usage and disabling it will fix the issue.

`$ systemctl disable --now systemd-oomd`

After running this, I was not able to reproduce this issue on my build machine.

Reference(s):

1. https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/701605
2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404888/how-do-i-disable-the-systemd-oom-process-killer-in-ubuntu-22-04